# H.264 video file size from camera is much bigger than x264 output

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have a UVC camera which supports h264 protocol. we can see the h264 listed below when we list all formats supported.

```
msm8909:/data # ./ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video1
ffmpeg version N-53546-g5eb4405fc5-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-libgme --enable-gray --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 56.100 / 56. 56.100
  libavcodec     58. 97.100 / 58. 97.100
  libavformat    58. 49.100 / 58. 49.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x4649140] Compressed:        h264 :                H.264 : 1920x1080 1280x720 640x480 320x240
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x4649140] Compressed:       mjpeg :                MJPEG : 1920x1080 1280x720 640x480 320x240
```

I am running the ffmpeg cmd to record UVC camera video to local device.

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format h264 -framerate 30 -video_size 1280*720 -i /dev/video1 -c copy /sdcard/Movies/output.mkv
```

The video size is way bigger than running the command below:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1280*720 -i /dev/video1 -c:v libx264 -vf format=yuv420p /sdcard/Movies/output.mp4
```

I assume the camera already supports h264 protocol. Thus I don't need to re-encode to 264 formats. However, the video size does not look like an H264 encoded video.

Answer (score 0):

## Not all H.264 encoders are equal

x264 is a very efficient H.264 encoder meaning it provides a higher quality at a lower bitrate.

Your camera has a comparatively inefficient H.264 encoder. It is optimized for speed on a small piece of hardware with limited resources. So it is unable to do the fancy stuff that x264 can. Result is a much higher bitrate for a similar quality.